# Pushnotification not working properly

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

Hello all I am following [this](https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services) example I am able to generate registration token, but I am not able to get notification in my phone, can any one help me with this?

When I try to check using this http://connect-survey.com/APK/bans_push/ I'm getting this error now:

> {"multicast_id":6837230096397340828,"success":0,"failure":1,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"error":"MismatchSenderId"}]}

Comment: Well did you replace the package name in Manifest from google's package name to your application package name ??

Comment: <receiver
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmReceiver"
            android:exported="true"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

                <category android:name="PACKAGE NAME" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

Comment: hmmmmm did you add the internet permission ??

Comment: Then please show us some code so that we can find the error because the information is not compete

Comment: Did you change the package name of the below services in the manifest ::       android:name="gcm.play.android.samples.com.gcmquickstart.MyGcmListenerService"       android:name="gcm.play.android.samples.com.gcmquickstart.MyInstanceIDListenerService" android:name="gcm.play.android.samples.com.gcmquickstart.RegistrationIntentService"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105427/discussion-between-jolly-and-rakshit-nawani).

Comment: I am also experiencing the same error. Have u got any  solutions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that there is a difference between the "Project ID" (that usually appears in the url/console dashboard) and the actual 12-digit "Project Number".

Verify you're using the **Project Number** which can be found in the google console under project settings.

[Take a look at this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q1d1k.png)

Comment: Please flush out this answer to show how you can apply this information to the problem.

Comment: I edited my answer as you suggested. By the way, if you post the device id received on your server, the column must be of type varchar 256 (ascii) or larger, otherwise the id will be truncated and make issues.